# MySQL schedule event : database backup including date in the outfile

Tags: mysql, events, date-format

I am struggling now in order to automatize my tiny backup system. I managed to gather some piece of code but I cannot make it.

```
SET @sql_text = 
   CONCAT (
   "SELECT * FROM commandes INTO OUTFILE 'Y:/folder/Archives/BDD-commandes-CSV"
   , DATE_FORMAT( NOW(), '%Y%m%d')
   , "commandes.csv'"
);

PREPARE s1 FROM @sql_text;

CREATE EVENT BackUpCSV
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 HOUR
STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 DAY
ENDS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 YEAR
DO
  BEGIN
    EXECUTE s1;
  END |

DROP PREPARE s1;
```

Here is what i tried to do. An error is spotted at line 7 where it is actually a blank line ('#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 7')

I would be grateful to get this help. thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is all about delimiter. Here is the version which is fine to compile:

```
SET @sql_text = 
   CONCAT (
   "SELECT * FROM commandes INTO OUTFILE 'Y:/folder/Archives/BDD-commandes-CSV"
   , DATE_FORMAT( NOW(), '%Y%m%d')
   , "commandes.csv'"
);

PREPARE s1 FROM @sql_text;

delimiter |

CREATE EVENT BackUpCSV
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 HOUR
STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 DAY
ENDS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 YEAR
DO
  BEGIN
    EXECUTE s1;
  END |

delimiter ;

DROP PREPARE s1;
```

Also, I recommend to add `drop event if exists BackUpCSV |`

ps. I'm not sure this script will work

Comment: That is awesome, I did not know about delimiter. I ll check this further although your script worked fine for me.

Comment: Well, when I write this in the SQL textaera (phpmyadmin) it basically add an event, but the event doest work :s

[screenshot of what I see](http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/168689Sanstitre.jpg)

Comment: As I told you previously "I'm not sure this script will work". You need to encapsulate logic in event instead of something weird with prepared statement

Answer (score 0):

For that purposes better use shell script, or command line. Something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

mysqldump --add-drop-table -h <hostname> -u <username> --password=<password> --all-databases > filename.sql
filename="filename.sql."`eval date +%Y%m%d`".tgz"
tar -czf $filename filename.sql 
rm filename.sql
```

You can save this to a file, and run that file as a cron job.
If you want you can even push that archive file to another system with same script.

Of course you should understand that in this case you're storing your database credentials in a plain file. But if someone has access to the filesystem I'm sure s/he will find your application config files where you do exactly the same.

Comment: I just want to avoid cron job since im working in local. But thanx, this might be helpful sometimes :)